# Any Site That Displays The Received Text?

Tags: php, post, get, echo

So pretty much what I am looking for is a site that simply accepts POST requests, and the site then just displays the text received from the POST request.

For example, lets say that I POSTed "Hello, world!" to the site, if I looked at the contents of the page, it just said "Hello, world!". I need this for testing/developing purposes.

If not, could somebody possibly create a PHP script for this? I don't know PHP, otherwise I would do it myself :)

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry for the extremely easy question, I didn't realise it was this easy. Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Why not learn PHP and write the script? Or pay somebody to do it for you

Comment: <?php
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
 echo " $k = $v ";
}
?>

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
print_r($_POST);
```

This uses [`print_r`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to dump the content of the [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array. The page content type of text/plain is needed to prevent creating an [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own! Do this on any website you have

Simply `print_r($_POST);` should suffice on a blank page

Comment: `echo $_POST` most likely will result in `Array`

Comment: Sorry, yes. Updated my answer. Haven't had a coffee yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 First create a file names mypage.php then save this code.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['myText']))
  {
        echo $_POST['myText']
  }
  <form action='mypage.php'>
    <input type='text' name='myText'>
    <input type='submit'>
  </form>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your form looks like this

```
<form method="POST">
   <input type='text' name='field'>
   <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

The simplest way is write this code below it

```
<?php var_export($_POST); ?>
```